# Making second api call after first api call returns data

Tags: node.js, api, synchronous

I have two seperate functions that make API calls to different endpoints for return JSON Data using BlueBirdPromise.

```
 const searchVenues = (type) => {
  logger.debug('getVenues : type = ' + type);

  const config = {
    url: urlAPIServer + '/venue/available',
    qs: {
      type,
    },
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': dataApiKey
    }
  };

  return new BluebirdPromise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(config, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  });
};

const getVenuesWithCuisine = () => {
  logger.debug('getVenuesWithCuisine');

  const config = {
    url: urlAPIServer + '/venue/viewvenuewithcuisine',
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': dataApiKey
    }
  };

  return new BluebirdPromise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(config, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Invoking the funtions seperately to get the data from the API and bind it to variable.

```
searchVenues(venueType).then((venues) => {
      checkContextTimeout(context);
      conversationContext.venueType = venueType;
      conversationContext.venues = venues;
      context.skill = conversationContext; 
    });

    getVenuesWithCuisine().then((venueswithcuisines) => {
      conversationContext.venue_details = venueswithcuisines[0}["venue_details"];
      conversationContext.cuisines = venueswithcuisines[1]["cuisines"];
      conversationContext.venueType = venueType;
      conversationContext.venues = venuesJson.venues;
      continueConversation(request, response, context);
    });
```

The problem with above implementation is, if for some reason getVenuesWithCuisine completed first before searchVenues the continueConversation is getting invokes making           `conversationContext.venues = venues` as null.

How can i make these API calls synchronous so that the second API call is made only after the first one returns data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promise.all instead of doing it synchronously. That will resolve once both of your promises resolve and give you the results.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

```
Promise.all([searchVenues(venueType), getVenuesWithCuisine()]).then(function([venueResp, cuisineResp]) {
  ...
});
```